# is(:visible) selector not working on class jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Not sure how to explain this, I made a fiddle of what I'm attempting to do:
http://jsfiddle.net/x2btM/9/

here's my code:
HTML:

```
<div id="ZodOneDragBox">
    <div id="aquariusSelectedComp1" class="killSelectedComp1" style="display:none;">
        <img src="some.jpg">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="ZodTwoDragBox">
    <div id="aquariusSelectedComp2" class="killSelectedComp2" style="display:none;">
        <img src="some.jpg" width="45" height="45">
    </div>
</div>


<div id="aquariusIcnClick" class="iconClicker">
        <img src="some_Icon.jpg" width="45" height="45">
</div>
```

Here's my jquery:

```
if ($('.killSelectedComp1').is(':visible')) {
    //--SELECT BOX TWO
    $('#aquariusIcnClick').click(function() {
        $('.killSelectedComp2').hide();
        $('#aquariusSelectedComp2').show();
    });


}
else {
    //--SELECT BOX ONE
    $('#aquariusIcnClick').click(function() {
        $('.killSelectedComp1').hide();
        $('#aquariusSelectedComp1').show();
    });

}​
```

Basically when you click on `aquariusIcnClick` the image `aquariusSelectedComp1` will appear in div `ZodOneDragBox`. `aquariusSelectedComp1` with the class of `killSelectedComp1` is now visible, so when you click on the icon `aquariusIcnClick` again, the image should appear in `ZodTwoDragBox`. It works for the first box, but the selector is not reading that the image with the corresponding class is currently visible therefor executing what's in the `if` statement and showing the image in the second box. Hope I explained this well enough, once again, here's my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/x2btM/9/

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, I've googled to make sure that I'm using the `:visible` selector correctly any and all help is very much appreciated. Thank you
​

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you don't need bind your click on div condition instead check your div visibility onclick

```
    $('#aquariusIcnClick').click(function() {
         if ($('.killSelectedComp1').is(':visible')) {       
           $('.killSelectedComp2').hide();
           $('#aquariusSelectedComp2').show();
         }
         else
         {
           $('.killSelectedComp1').hide();
           $('#aquariusSelectedComp1').show();
         }
    });
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x2btM/10/)
​

Comment: Ohhhh, this makes sense!! Thank you Rahul, you were the first to answer, it won't let me accept your answer for another 5 minutes. Thank You once again!

Comment: @user1053263 no problem :) all the best

Answer (score 2):

Your code is only being executed once when the page loads / or the dom is ready. This means that your `if statement` is only tested once. You need to modify your code so that the if statement occurs within the click handler. This will mean the visibility of `killSelectedComp1` is tested each time the click occurs and you can then make your decision on what to do.

As @rahul has done ;)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this pebbl

Comment: no problem at all, in future if something doesn't seem to be working as you expect throw in a couple of `alert()` or `console.log()` commands in the area you are testing to visually see what is being executed where and when -- for me that has always helped catch issues of this type. good luck w/ it :)

Answer (score 2):

Do not bind event condition rather put condition in the event

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x2btM/11/)**

```
$('#aquariusIcnClick').click(function() {
    if ($('.killSelectedComp1').is(':visible')) {
        $('.killSelectedComp2').hide();
        $('#aquariusSelectedComp2').show();
    }
    else {
        $('.killSelectedComp1').hide();
        $('#aquariusSelectedComp1').show();
    }
});​
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this Adil